# FIFO Queue Implementation

Tags: java, array, queue

My Implementation of a FIFO queue. I am mainly curious about my initialization of empty generic arrays.

```
public class Queue<T> {

    T queue[];
    public Queue()
    {
        queue = (T[])new Object[0];
    }

    public T pop()
    {
        T queue2[] = (T[])new Object[queue.length-1];
        T obj = queue[0];
        for(int i = 0; i < queue.length-1; i++)
            queue2[i] = queue[i+1];
        queue = queue2;
        return obj;
    }

    public void push(T node)
    {
        T queue2[] = (T[])new Object[queue.length+1];       
        for(int i = 0; i < queue.length; i++)
        {
            queue2[i] = queue[i];
        }
        queue2[queue.length] = node;
        queue = queue2;
    }

    public T peek()
    {
        return queue[0];
    } 

    public int size()
    {
        return queue.length;
    }

}
```

Comment: you know, you can you LinkedList....

Comment: or ConcurrentLinkedQueue

Answer (score 4):

Trying to use [a generic array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/how-to-create-a-generic-array-in-java) in Java, is a disaster waiting to happen. The `T[]` field is really an `Object[]` at runtime, and trying to do otherwise just hides this fact. It makes you think you're dealing with a `T[]`, but it's a lie; you're really dealing with an `Object[]`. There are [very good reasons not to use generic arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2927391/whats-the-reason-i-cant-create-generic-array-types-in-java). I'll add that if you peek into the current Oracle implementation of [`ArrayList`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/ArrayList.java?av=f#134) or [`CopyOnWriteArrayList`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.java?av=f#99), you won't see a generic array being used, but `Object[]` explicitly. It makes it clear to the developers and to the readers that the array being handled does not have a generic type.

In your particular case, there are no unsafe operations done with it, so that's good. But be careful if you add a `toArray()` method in the future... Just take a look to see how easy it is to make a mistake: add the method

```
public T[] toArray() {
    return queue; // or queue.clone();
}
```

Looks fine. Even compiles without warnings. Now do:

```
Queue<String> queue = new Queue<>();
queue.push("foo");
String[] array = queue.toArray();
```

Looks also fine. Still no warnings. But this will fail at run-time:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String;

Runtime is the worst moment to have those exceptions. It is always better to detect bugs as early as possible, and fail directly at compile-time. And this exception, is because the array really isn't a `String[]`, but an `Object[]`. There are ways around that of course (the simpler being to return `Object[]` from the method), but the point is that you're opening yourself to a lot of unforeseen troubles. All in all, if you really want a backing array, don't lie to yourself and:

- Just use `Object[]`. You'll have to cast when `pop`ing or `push`ing elements, but you can ensure that it is safe to do by having the proper generic type for the methods, just like you have in the current code.
- If you want strong typing, pass the class of the elements as constructor to the `Queue`.

Couple of side-notes:

- It would be preferable to throw an `NoSuchElementException` if the queue is empty inside `peek`, instead of failing with an out of bounds exception.
- To copy arrays, you can use `System.arraycopy`, like mentioned [in this other answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/145142/95296).

Comment: Wow It never occurred to me to use Object instead of T. That is brilliant. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The most efficient way to copy arrays as you want is using: `System.arraycopy()`. So, I would suggest you to replace your loops with `System.arraycopy` calls.

In the `pop()` method instead of copying one by one like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < queue.length-1; i++)
    queue2[i] = queue[i+1];
```

`System.arraycopy` can be used as:

```
System.arraycopy(queue, 1, queue2, 0, queue.length-1);
```

And in the `push()` method, instead of copying one by one like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < queue.length; i++)
{
    queue2[i] = queue[i];
}
```

You could use:

```
System.arraycopy(queue, 0, queue2, 0, queue.length);
```

See also [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32806173/copying-arrays-the-right-way).

Comment: did he ask about copying?

Comment: @OhadR I thought that my answer made an "insightful observation" as mentioned in [What goes into an answer](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)